# Error: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'colorlog' distribution was not found and is required by Cactus

Tags: django, terminal, cactus

To upload my Django project in netlify, I installed cactus and am trying to build my site.

```
cactus create ~/mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cactus", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3081, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'colorlog' distribution was not found and is required by Cactus
```

I already installed colorlog by

```
pip3 install colorlog --user
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error, worked with `sudo cactus serve`